# How to Integrate Drools Flows and Rules with my web application

Tags: java, drools-flow

sorry for my language,My question is how to Integrate Drools technology to my web-application,please tell me step by step because i am a learner so please tell me.I already read this document(http://downloads.jboss.com/drools/docs/5.1.1.34858.FINAL/drools-flow/html/ch14) but i need more clarity that means fully architecture or please send me any u r sample web-app with Drools technology as a ZIP file or war file. i will unzip then copy in to my eclipse workspace. Please i will report any sample web-application with drools  on tomorrow to my Project lead.

Thanks,
Abhi.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should never, *ever* unzip a JAR file like that.  Just add it to your classpath by putting it in your WEB-INF/lib and start writing classes.

Comment: thank you for u r response,here not possible to send all project as a zip file,so that if u possible just send a sample project as a zip file to my skype id(abhinavsskype) please..

Comment: No, that's not how things are done here.  I'm not at your beck and call.  You'll have to do some thinking.  I'd read this: http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/WebComponents3.html